# Stop arcpy.CopyFeatures_management from adding copied feature classes to TOC

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, features, copy

I've written a script that copies several feature classes to a new file gdb. Unfortunately CopyFeatures_management automatically adds the new feature classes to the TOC.

Is there a way to suppress this behaviour?

```
import arcpy, os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]    
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)

from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
outgdb = r"C:\\temp\\test.gdb"
for lyr in layers:
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        outfc = os.path.join(outgdb,os.path.split(lyr.dataSource)[-1]) 
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr.longName, outfc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [environment setting addOutputsToMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/env.htm) to False:

> Set whether tools' resulting output datasets should be added to the
> application display.

```
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
```